# How to know what is the current URL seen in browser when the URL is rewritten and opening an other page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Example :

If I write `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/documents/page/index.php?id=something`, and that I rewrite the page for that it loads `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php` in background, how can the PHP code in index.php knows that the previous page's path and query was `folder/documents/page/index.php?id=something` (with the query) ?

Will using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`do the job or they will give me the rewritten values ?

Else, is there an pother way to know what is in the URL bar ? Actually, the thing I need the `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php` to do is to load a page located on an other site but with the previous URL ending. I NEED a way to achieve this and to know in the PHP code what is the URL of the current page. The current page opened and seen by clients being like `http://www.mydomain.com/folder/documents/page/index.php?id=something` but running the script `http://www.mydomain.com/index.php`.

Thanks for your help I have a deadline soon, and I didn't figured out yet a way to achieve this. I searched for hours without finding a reasonable answer.

Comment: Well, about the `$_SERVER` vars, why don't you simply try out yourself before asking here?

Comment: You want the URL of the previous page OR the current page on which you are currently standing.

Comment: AFAIK scripts have no knowledge about the "original" url that was rewritten before they were called. You can however add an additional query argument during the rewrite process and hand over that information like this.

Comment: Can you post your existing `.htaccess` code?

Comment: Yes, I opened a new question about it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817471/rewrite-everything-to-index-php-but-be-able-to-know-what-page-it-came-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` OR `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` to return rewrite address.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it works. I got to deal with an other problem in order to test this out.